# Is $\frak c = \aleph_1$?

Tags: cardinals

Is $\frak c = \aleph_1$?

My textbook requires me to find out the cardinality of $I(\Bbb N)$, which is a set of all infinite subset of $\Bbb N$

What I found is cardinality of $I(\Bbb N)$ equals to $2^{\aleph_0} = \frak c$ then is it also okay to denote that $\frak c =\aleph_1$?

Comment: [It is undecidable in ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis), so my guess is that you are not supposed to say it.

Comment: This is the *Continuum Hypothesis*.

Comment: What's the definition of $\aleph_1$ and why do you think that $|I(\mathbb N)| = \aleph_1?$ If you don't think that why were you motivated to conclude $c=\aleph_1?$ As others have alluded to, whether or not that equality holds is a somewhat famous question and has been proven to have no easy answer.